# Percent of time series in specific range by day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large time series dataset that measures temperature over time. Each row has a date-time and corresponding temperature. I want to figure out the percentage of time that it is in a specific temperature range.

I would like to go through this data frame and for each day, calculate the percentage of the temperatures that are between 10 and 20 degrees. That should result in a new data frame that, for each day, has the percentage that the device was in range. The point is to see how the percentage in range is changing by day rather than just calculating the percentage in range for the whole data frame.

How can I achieve this in a more efficient way than what I have attempted?

```
df1 = df[(df['date'] > '2019-01-01') & (df['date'] <= '2019-01-02')]
df2 = df[(df['date'] > '2019-01-02') & (df['date'] <= '2019-01-03')]
df3 = df[(df['date'] > '2019-01-03') & (df['date'] <= '2019-01-04')]
df4 = df[(df['date'] > '2019-01-04') & (df['date'] <= '2019-01-05')]
df5 = df[(df['date'] > '2019-01-05') & (df['date'] <= '2019-01-06')]
df6 = df[(df['date'] > '2019-01-06') & (df['date'] <= '2019-01-07')]
df7 = df[(df['date'] > '2019-01-07') & (df['date'] <= '2019-01-08')]

condition1 = df1[(df1.temp >= 10.0) & (df1.temp <=20.0)]
condition2 = df2[(df2.temp >= 10.0) & (df2.temp <=20.0)]
condition3 = df3[(df3.temp >= 10.0) & (df3.temp <=20.0)]
condition4 = df4[(df4.temp >= 10.0) & (df4.temp <=20.0)]
condition5 = df5[(df5.temp >= 10.0) & (df5.temp <=20.0)]
condition6 = df6[(df6.temp >= 10.0) & (df6.temp <=20.0)]
condition7 = df7[(df7.temp >= 10.0) & (df7.temp <=20.0)]

percentage1 = (len(condition1)/len(df1))*100
percentage2 = (len(condition2)/len(df2))*100
percentage3 = (len(condition3)/len(df3))*100
percentage4 = (len(condition4)/len(df4))*100
percentage5 = (len(condition5)/len(df5))*100
percentage6 = (len(condition6)/len(df6))*100
percentage7 = (len(condition7)/len(df7))*100
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Are your timestamps at regular frequencies, or do you need to calculate the duration for each set of measurements above the threshold?

Comment: The timestamps are every 10 min.  They look like this:                                                                 1/1/19 0:02 17.8
1/1/19 0:12 17.7
1/1/19 0:22 17.7
1/1/19 0:32 17.7
1/1/19 0:42 17.7
1/1/19 0:52 17.6
1/1/19 1:02 17.6
1/1/19 1:12 17.6
1/1/19 1:22 17.6
1/1/19 1:32 17.6
1/1/19 1:42 17.5
1/1/19 1:52 17.5

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have equally sampled data you can try this:

```
df2 = df[(df['temperature']>10)&(df['temperature']<20)]['temperature'].resample('1d').count().divide(df['temperature'].resample('1d').count())
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this could work for you:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #not necessary if your dates are already in datetime format
df.set_index('date',inplace=True) #make date the index

all_days=df.index.normalize().unique() #get all unique days in timeseries

df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','percent']) #create new df to store results
df2['date']=all_days #make date column equal to the unique days
df2.set_index('date',inplace=True) #make date column the index

for i,row in df2.iterrows(): #iterate through each row of df2
    iloc = df2.index.get_loc(i) #get index location
    daily_df = df[(df.index >= df2.index[iloc]) & (df.index < df2.index[iloc+1])] #get reduced df for that day (assuming it starts at midnight and ends at 23:59:59)
    total_count = daily_df.shape[0] #number of temp readings that day
    above_count = daily_df[(daily_df['temp'] >= 10) & (daily_df['temp'] <= 20)].values.shape[0] #number of temp readings between 10 and 20
    df2.iloc[iloc]['percent']=100*above_count/total_count #assign percent column the percentage of values between 10 and 20
```

there's definitely a way to boil down the code with pandas functions that I'm unaware of..but is a good start

you will have to handle the last day as it will not have a bounding end day

EDIT

replace the daily_df line with:

```
daily_df = df[df.index.normalize() == df2.index[iloc]]
```

and won't crash on the last date